# Empty input validation not working

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, connect

I have been having a few issues trying to get the following script to validate inputs.

```
app = connect()
.use(connect.bodyParser())  #So we can get the post data.
.use(req,res) ->
    valid = false if (req.body.name is "") or (req.body.question is "") or (req.body.email is "")  #Was all the data submitted?

    if valid
        #process request

http.createServer(app).listen(1407)
```

In order to debug I have used console.log to list the inputs, where it returns two inputs, one with the correct data and another `undefined`

I was previously using `req.body.name?` as well, but it is only rewriting as `req.body.question != null` and not checking for undefined.

The HTML form

```
<form action="_serverurl_" method="post">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" name="name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your Email" name="email">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" name="subject">
    <textarea name="question" placeholder="Question"></textarea>
    <div class="right"><input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="Send"></div>
</form>
```

The part confusing me the most is why there are two inputs to the server?

*Debug info:*

- Node Version: v0.10.21
- Connect Version: v2.12.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I can't see why your code would not work, but an approach may be splitting it into smaller manageable components.
For validation you could define a function, that allows you to determine whether a field is valid or not (see `isFieldValid` below).

```
isFieldValid = (field) -> field? and field.length > 0

app = connect()
.use(connect.bodyParser())  #So we can get the post data.
.use (req,res) ->
    # pickup the body vars first to ease reading
    {name, email, subject, question} = req.body
    # valid should be always defined, even if it's only true/false
      # Was all the data submitted?
    valid = isFieldValid(name) and isFieldValid(email) and isFieldValid(question)
    if valid
      # process request
    else 
      # handle invalid data
      res.send(400, ...)
```

If you're looking for a more elaborate validation library I'd recommend [Validator](https://github.com/chriso/validator.js).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Works perfectly, I have no idea why it never before.

I also didn't realise that you could use `{name, etc} = req.body` to refer to create variables, real help!  Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel The [Destructuring Assignment](http://coffeescript.org/#destructuring) section of the manual might be of interest to you.

Comment: Guys the last `.use(` statement is missing its `)` in both question and answer.  If you leave this on the Internet, you might break Google.  (I would just drop the `(` since the only/last parameter is a callback function.)